# How do I get the Create date from a object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

Hello I have an app in rails and i need to retrive the create date from an object.
I know that rails use timestamps to automatically save this info, and i looked at the .json ant it have the Created_at info. The question is how do i access this info (Created_at) from the object ( my intention is order by create time, and show this too)

Tks to any help

Comment: Could you show us what you currently have? It would be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can access that property in the following way:

```
u = User.first   # Let's pretend there's a `User` model within the rails application. Here im getting the first record and storing that user in the variable `u`.

u[:created_at]  # This will give me the value for the `created_at`, for instance: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 14:42:44 UTC +00:00 

or

u.created_at  # will give you the same result
```

If you want to `sort` by that field, you could (following the assumption that there's a `User` model for instance) use the `sort_by`:

```
User.all.sort_by &:created_at  # This is just a demonstration, you might want to get a sub-set of whatever model you're querying with `where` and some relevant criteria.
```

Or

```
   User.find(:all, :order => "created_at")  # old and deprecated approach
```

Or

```
   User.order("created_at DESC") #  more recent approach
```